# How to decrypt Adopted Storage?

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

Using the SD card as Adopted Storage encrypts it. How can it be decrypted?

Comment: I think current versions of Android do not use the term _Adopted Storage_ they use _SD card formatted as internal storage_.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## **How to decrypt adopted storage.**

1. Your Android device must be rooted.
2. Browse to `/data/misc/vold`, e.g. using a file browser app like "ES Explorer".
3. The `.key` file there is the encryption key of your adopted storage.
4. View the 16-byte key using a graphical hex editor or alternatively run `hexdump -e '/1 "%02x"' filename_here.key`.
5. Mount your SD card e.g. using a GNU/Linux system. In my case, SD card was mounted at `/dev/sdb2`.
6. Then run this command to decrypt the drive:

   ```
   dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 <Put the 16-byte hex key here> 0 /dev/sdb2 0"
   ```

   **Some types of errors/warnings can be ignored**.
7. If your key is correct, you can mount it by `mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/crypt1 /mnt/1/`
8. Finally, you can run `cd /mnt/1` to browse the decrypted storage.

Comment: Related: [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135803/16575). The answer is similar, but gives an alternative approach to finding the 16-byte key.

Comment: Is it possible to generate the .key keyfile from a known password/pin code and access to the device? Or is the key completely random? In my case, my internal storage is wiped, so I don't have access to the original keyfile anymore.

Comment: @zerwas the right thing is that you copy your key after making your SD as internal, but you can for sure encrypt your storage same as android do and make a key then put it there it will work but if you copy your key once its done by the phone it will be much simpler

Comment: the full manual has the correct way of extracting the key using `od`: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html

Comment: I have unrooted encrypted Android 10 device and I don't see anything of mentioned in p. 2-3. I don't have `/data` folder in my root storage, no `vold` folder and I don't have any `.key` file. When I search my root storage for `vold` string, all I can see are `vold.fstab` and `vold.rc` files. When I search for `.key`, I am getting a bunch of files with `.so` extension having `.keymaster` as a part of file name and now file with filename ending in `.key`. Is it because these are available only on rooted phone or because this answer is a little bit out dated and no longer valid for Android 10?

Comment: @trejder root access is required for /data/misc/vold