# mount marshmallow encrypted external sdcard

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mount

How can i mount sdcard in linux ?

I have already tried using this command to pull the  key from data partiton.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 /dev/sdb2 sdb2  --key-file 1.key
```

And this error shows up;

```
Device /dev/sdb2 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Comment: What kind of encryption? Did you use it as [adoptable storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)? Then please see: [How to decrypt adopted storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/16575)