# How to migrate an adopted storage sdcard to another?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, adoptable-storage

So I've recently tried out marshmallow and kind of like the adopted storage idea as I never find myself removing the micro sdcard.

I'm curious though if there is a smooth way to upgrade to a bigger or better sdcard later on. Right now I would probably attempt to rsync with adb to a PC and insert a new card, format it and rsync back. I'm not very confident this will work however.

Perhaps it's faster to mount both cards in linux using this method: [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)
and sync them there.