# Can i manually decrypt a folder encrypted with ES File Explorer?

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, es-file-explorer

I had **encrypted a folder using ES File explorer**. Then later on, I upgraded my **ROM from cm12 to cm13**. And then, I was not able to decrypt the data with ES file explorer, after the OS update.

**I know the key** used for encryption. Is it possible to decrypt the data manually?

I thought it was not possible, but then i saw this post [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage) And now i believe there is a solution for my problem too.

Comment: "I was not able to decrypt the data with ES file explorer" - What happened when you tried?

Comment: It worked till i flashed and changed my ROM. Once i changed the ROM, ES won't accept my decryption key.

Comment: Try this tutorial link - https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-decrypt-an-encrypted-ES-explorer-file-without-the-password And this - http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/159398/es-file-explorer-forgotten-password.aspx Hope I helped, Sid