# Mount `corrupted` adoptable storage

Tags: adoptable-storage

I have an SD card that is formatted as an adoptable storage.

This morning, I tried to delete photos from my phone but the operation failed and after that my SD card cannot be read by the device.

I inserted the SD card in my tablet and the tablet says the device is not supported.

I also tried accessing it from my Linux computer but running it can't be mounted. Running `sudo fdisk -l` displays in the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x870c5a1b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 459380735 459378688 219.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       459382782 500117503  40734722  19.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       459382784 500117503  40734720  19.4G 82 Linux swap / 
Solaris


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 59.8 GiB, 64222134272 bytes, 125433856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A5B52D41-3B56-978D-9A23-B12B54DAD545

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2048     34815     32768   16M unknown
/dev/mmcblk0p2 34816 125433822 125399007 59.8G unknown
```

I'm assuming the details of the SD card is the last 2 entries there and their `Type`s are unknown...

According to the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145446/214764), there's a way to decrypt and recover the files but given that I can't even mount my device on my computer, I'm lost.

Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, mounting the volume as f2fs did the job.

Comment: Could you elaborate in this answer? Give more details of exactly what and how you repaired, recovered, or mounted the volume?