# How to dump Android's external SDcard that is used as internal memory?

Tags: adb, sd-card, mount, partitions

although StackExchange sites have helped me a lot in the past, it's now the first time to actively post a question here.

I have an issue with my Motorola Moto G which is running with Android 7.1.1 (Lineage OS) - I was searching throughout the whole Internet but w/o success.

I want to do some forensic work on the memory of this device. It has an internal flash, and an external SDcard, which is formatted in a way to extend the internal memory as well. I think, since Android Marshmallow there is this option to do that.

I can dump the internal userdata partition and mount on my Linux PC w/o problems:

```
# ADB Shell:
-> ls -l /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/ 
      ... userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p42 
# Host PC:
-> adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p42 mmcblk0p42.img
-> sudo mount -o loop mmcblk0p42.img mmcblk0p42
-> ls mmcblk0p42
       adb app-ephemeral backup ...
```

I am trying the same with the external SD-Card formatted as internal:

```
# ADB Shell:
-> ls -la /dev/block/platform/soc.0/7864900.sdhci/by-name/ 
      ... android_expand -> /dev/block/mmcblk1p2
# Host PC:
-> adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk1p2  mmcblk1p2.img
-> sudo mount -o loop mmcblk1p2.img mmcblk1p2
       mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

What is wrong here? If I put the SDcard to a card reader then the partition are recognized but cannot be mounted due to unknown file system.

Any help is very appreciated. *Jens*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: Did you enabled encryption in settings>security ?

Comment: Nope! No encryption