# SD card formatted as internal storage Recovery Data

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, data-recovery, adoptable-storage

I have a problem. I formatted uin SD-Card with a smartphone with Android 6 and asked me to format it as internal memory, I accepted, with only one clause, if I moved the SD on another device this did not recognize it.
Now, I have formatted the smartphone and I reinserted the SD-Card, in the same, only asking me to reformat it so I will lose all the data I have.

How can I recover them?

Through Gparted I noticed that the sd-Card is divided into two partitions.

There is no way to enter the partitions or to recognize the sd at the same smartphone?

---

I do not think I understood the reason. that is, if I had not restored it to the factory settings, I could recover the key and be able to use it to enter the SD card.
Can not recover the key from the SD card instead of the smartphone?

PS. sorry if I wrote here, I can not find the button to reply.

Comment: You can consider *accepting* the answer of acejavelin by ticking the green arrow next to it , if it fully answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

This question appears to be a  duplicate of [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/131553)
in many regards, but if I understand it correctly, the following things happened and one step makes it unique:

1. You adopted the microSD card as internal storage
2. You removed it from the device (reason isn't relevant)
3. *While the microSD card was removed, you factory reset (formatted) the
   phone*
4. You re-inserted the microSD card after the reset was complete, and
   the data is unreadable

If this is the correct summation of your situation, then I am sorry, but your data on the microSD card is lost permanently, and cannot be recovered.

When an SD card is "adopted" as internal storage, it is encrypted with a random encryption token (a digital "key" so to speak) so that data can only be read or written to by that device for security and privacy. Any data recovery attempt of the information on the card requires the encryption token from the device, which is generated randomly when the storage card is adopted, if you formatted the device the token was permanently erased like all other transient device data, and the storage cannot be decrypted or recovered by any known means.

Your only real option now is to reformat the card and start clean, and unless you really need the space as internal, use the card as external (portable) storage.

For more clarity in to why this is impossible, and what is necessary for the data to be recovered, you can reference [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage) question.