# Restoring adopted storage key which was forgotten

Tags: storage

is it possible to restore adopted storage key which was forgotten? I have rooted android phone, I tried to navigate to /data/misc/vold/ folder with TWRP, but it seems that the key is lost forever?

Thanks

[image: Photo of vold folder]

Comment: Did you root (unlock the bootloader) after forgetting it? Unlocking the bootloader will usually wipe the system, including the key. See [this Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181500/44325) (which has been mentioned in your [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230700/44325)).

Comment: Hello, root and unlocking bootloader was done much earlier before SD card was forgotten.

Comment: create partition image and try testdisk