# How can I access/retrieve data from an SD card formatted as internal storage from my PC?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, data-recovery, linux, broken-screen

**My phone's screen broke and I would like to retrieve the data on the external SD (which was used as internal storage).**

Using KDE's partition manager tool I can see on my Linux Mint 19.1 that this is the structure of the SD:

```
 29,81 GB Storage

Partition    Type      Dimension

sdb1         fat32     16MB

sdb2         unknown   29,80GB
```

I can mount sdb1 with no problems, but inside there is only a folder named "Android" containing 3 folders with no files inside it (see picture)
[image: Only 3 apps directories are available]

All those folders are also empty.

**My question is, is this 29,80GB partition encrypted or my phone wasn't at all using the SD card?**

I never encrypted the internal memory, also I had internal space problems (which could mean the phone wasn't using the SD card as intented).

I couldn't find any information using search engines, and other similar answers on this website had no useful information.

Edit:

My phone is rooted and with debug USB enabled, it turns on fine, but with no screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: If it was adopted storage (ie. "internal storage"), and you are not already rooted, and cannot access the card in the device, basically you're screwed, the data is lost.

Comment: @acejavelin I checked and am now sure it was "Adopted storage" (also called "Internal storage").
Also my phone is rooted and has USB debug enabled, for some reason it doesn't currently allow me to connect to it with adb but before it worked.

Comment: As your device is rooted you could try to install app via recovery to the system partition or the user data partition if it is not encrypted. This app could autostart on BootCompleted and then provide somehow access to your data (if e.g. Wifi is enabled and still working). [This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395) looks a bit like the approach I described.