# memory card as internal storage

Tags: data-recovery, android-versions, formatting

My phone can't read my memory card and my memory card mounted as internal storage in marshmallow operating system. How can i get my data back?, in my setting it show memory 91 gb to 119gb but directory not exist, no data found all app that i run in my memory are gone. Some one please help me.

Comment: It could be that the memory card is defective. Have you tested it elsewhere?

Comment: i can't test because my device is linked with my memory card as internal storage. In my setting storage option my memory card show but not shows the data like app data etc..

Comment: Is it a removable microSD card? If so you can test it elsewhere and if it fails replace it. If not, take the phone to the nearest repair shop. It's that simple.

Comment: they format my memory card. My 91 gb data lost.. 

Comment: i know how to fix(root) but i don't know the process...

Comment: What process? If it was formatted the data is gone. The question now should be "does it work after being formatted?" If yes then keep using until it breaks; if not replace it. Your questions and your ramblings in comments doesn't make any sense.

Comment: my data is still in my memory card but i can't access.. that's all... and it's not formated.. it's shows 91gb but directory lost... so it can't find any data. that's all.

Comment: If it has become corrupted but not damaged then the solution is format or use a PC with specialized software to try to recover some of the data (very slim chance). That's ALL.

Comment: @Aman you can eject the SD card from settings and test it on some PC. Just don't format it. Then you can put the card back in phone. The bonding won't break until you don't "Forget" the SD card.

Comment: i use all the possibilities you mentioned but no data found....

Comment: i use many recovery software but nothing help me..

Comment: if your SD card is encrypted/adopted no external software will work. first thing i would do is make a snapshot with ddrescue for further analysis

Comment: As @alecxs mentioned, you cannot read SD card formatted as Adoptable storage on any other device. Connecting to PC is just to test if it's detected properly. If the point of your question is to recover data from Adoptable SD card, it's already been answered.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: ya it detected properly but format option pop up..