# Can't decrypt adopted storage

Tags: external-sd, linux, encryption, adoptable-storage, termux

Last night, I messed up my LineageOS 16 install on my Galaxy S5 and had to reinstall it, starting essentially from scratch. I wanted to see if there was any way I could decrypt the 128 GB microSD card I used as adopted storage and found this [tutorial](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145446). I got the key from a backup made using TWRP and tried it on Linux Mint 20 MATE (booting from USB), but it didn't work. The following command gave me an error:

```
dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /media/mint/4B2E-1F13` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 [16-BYTE HEX KEY] 0 /media/mint/4B2E-1F13 0"

blockdev: ioctl error on BLKGETSIZE: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.167 (2019-11-30) and kernel driver (unknown version).
```

Doing it with `sudo` gave me this error:

```
blockdev: ioctl error on BLKGETSIZE: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Invalid format on line 1 of table.
Command failed.
```

I couldn't even mount the SD card with Termux when after putting it back into my phone. Is my data unrecoverable? Do I have the wrong key? Thanks.

Comment: `/media/mint/4B2E-1F13` must be a directory. You need to provide the block device path to `dmsetup`. It must be something like `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`. Use `df` to see available block devices. Or see kernel log using `dmesg` when connecting SD card to PC. // Btw your question is about Linux, not Android.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16701326/9165920

Comment: @IrfanLatif I changed ```/media/mint/4B2E-1F13``` to ```/dev/mmcblk0p1``` (my SD card according to ```df -h```) and the error messages were the same except the ```BLKGETSIZE``` lines were replaced with ```blockdev: cannot open /dev/mmcblk0p1: Permission denied```. The same thing happens when inputting ```/dev/mmcblk0``` instead.

Comment: no need to nest `blockdev` in backticks just type value of partition size directly and use proper path to block device

Comment: @Pete block devices cannot be read without root. Run from a root shell or use `sudo` with `dmsetup` as well as `blockdev` (both are separate commands). Or write partition size directly as alecxs said to avoid using `blockdev` in subshell. Provide encrypted partition (`mmcblk0p1`), not whole SD card (`mmcblk0`).

Comment: @IrfanLatif My memory card actually appears to have 2 partitions. ```mmcblk0p1``` is ~17 MB and gets mounted automatically upon insertion at ```/media/mint/4B2E-1F13```. The file browser shows it as empty with ~127 GB free. There's an unmounted 2nd partition (~119 GB) called ```mmcblk0p2``` and I don't know if I can mount this (or if I even should). I think I'll try the command again, but with ````sudo``` before ```blockdev``` as well as ```dmsetup``` and use ```/dev/mmcblk0p1``` instead of ```/dev/mmcblk0``` and see what happens.

Comment: Then the encrypted partition is `/dev/mmcblk0p2`. You need to decrypt it before you can mount it. There is no visible filesystem on it until it's encrypted.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599682

Answer (score 1):

Good news: trying the following command successfully decrypted my SD card without any errors:

```
sudo dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `sudo blockdev --getsize /dev/mmcblk0p2` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 [16-BYTE HEX KEY] 0 /dev/mmcblk0p2 0"
```

A couple of minor issues:

- `sudo mount -t /dev/mmcblk0p2/crypt1 /media/mint/sd` returned the error `mount: /media/mint/sd: can't find in /etc/fstab.` I can view the content of the SD card in the file browser running as admin, however.
- Copying the files over to my laptop's Windows 10 SSD, some files and directories didn't get copied due to the presence of invalid characters in their names (mainly asterisks and colons in file names and a period in a folder name). Not sure how to deal with these...

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `-t` expects a filesystem type. Learning by trials is a good thing but having a brief look at manuals and existing web resources saves a lot of hassle: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the `ext4` part in poqdavid's answer in the question I linked lol. Thanks for the catch. I'm still not sure how to deal with files and directories with invalid filenames for Windows. It seems like only ext file systems can support those filenames, and Windows can only read that with 3rd-party programs. The other filesystems that Windows can use (exFAT and FAT32) don't support those filenames, so I don't think I can copy those files to flash drives formatted as either of those.

Comment: No way to force filesystems change their behavior. Such limitations are deep rooted in their design. For backup/restore purpose archive such files using `tar`, `zip` etc. Or batch rename such files if possible using `sed`, `mv` etc.

Comment: you can use `tar --transform` to convert file names during extraction to fat32 file system based on whitelist charset

Comment: *transform="--transform='s/[^][A-Za-z0-9 !#$%&'$'\047''()+,.\/;=@'$'\136''_\\`{}~'$'\177''-]/_/g'"; tar -c /media/mint/sd | tar $transform -vxC /media/mint/targetdrive*

Comment: ... still might overwrite case insensitive duplicates (like File.txt with file.txt) but this kind of copy will never fail