# Can someone please help me understand this Linux command?

Tags: sd-card, linux, adoptable-storage, external-display

```
dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 <Put the 16-byte hex key here> 0 /dev/sdb2 0"
```

I got it from step 6 of the first answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage).

I am trying to view the files on an android adopted SD card.

The card suddenly stopped working on my phone and I'm now trying to retrieve my files before I press on "forget" to unmount it from my phone and go back to using my phone normally on it's Internal memory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112652/discussion-on-question-by-jjrussel-can-someone-please-help-me-understand-this-li).

Answer (score 1):

`` `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` `` (in backticks) is a command to get partition size, where `/dev/sdb2` is the (encrypted) partition and most likely has a different name on your pc
`<Put the 16-byte hex key here>` is a placeholder for the real encryption key you have previously extracted from `/data/misc/vold`
`dmsetup create crypt1` is the actually command to decrypt `/dev/sdb2`
when successfull a new (decrypted) block device `/dev/mapper/crypt1` (ext4) will created

Note: root permissions required. open root shell with `sudo -i` before running this Linux command