# How can I clone an adopted SD card?

Tags: sd-card, adoptable-storage

I adopted an SD card as internal memory and one day it just suddenly stopped working.

With tremendous help from the member @alecxs I was able to make an img copy of it and browse the files in it. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage) is some of the basics of how that was done.

I'm not sure why it failed on the phone since if it was a physical problem with the SD card then shouldn't it NOT have been possible to read or decrypt it?

In any case, I have another (new) SD card and I would like to clone the old one on it so that I can effectively start using it as if it was the old one...basically everything to be as it was pre-SD card failure.

Is there a way to do that? How?

I'm able to see my photos which is a HUGE relief but my concern now is the app data that is un-viewable unless it's put back in the phone and opened with it's app.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138094/discussion-on-question-by-jjrussel-how-can-i-clone-an-adopted-sd-card).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- first copy sd.img to new MicroSD Card (it will finish unsucessful "error writing, not enough space")
- create another sd2.img from new MicroSD Card (the one which ended unsucessful, we just need raw sd2.img with correct size)
- run kpartx to map sd.img into /dev/mapper/loop1p1, /dev/mapper/loop1p2 and sd2.img into /dev/mapper/loop2p1, /dev/mapper/loop2p2 (may vary)
- create two new block devices for /dev/mapper/loop1p2 and /dev/mapper/loop2p2 (see link in your question)
- now lets assume /dev/mapper/loop1p2 is /dev/mapper/crypt1 (= sd.img) and /dev/mapper/loop2p2 is /dev/mapper/crypt2 (= sd2.img)
- crypt1 should be mountable as ext4 partition to any mount point (that's your old MicroSD Card)
- crypt2 is probably broken because of less size and must be formatted with mke2fs

  mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/crypt2
- now crypt2 should be mountable as ext4 too, mount to another mount point
- next, copy all files from one mount point to another. make sure you preserve secontext, xattrs, uid and file permissions. this can be done with `busybox cp -ac` or `tar --selinux --xattrs -p`

i am on mobile and busy today, will improve that answer later. btw i am not sure that's how it works at all (the dmsetup part)

good luck

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115424/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-how-can-i-clone-an-adopted-sd-card).