# SD Card Decryption on Samsung Galaxy M30

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, encryption

I encrypted the SD card in my Samsung M30 and then I factory restored the device. Now I can't access my files on the SD card. Can I recover the data that I stored on it? Are there any tools that can help with this? The SD size is 64GB.

Comment: Android uses sophisticated encryption for protecting your data. By performing a factory reset you have deleted the de-/dencryption key and a purpose of an encryption is to protect the data from users that don't have the key. This means the data is gone, you can't access it without breaking the encryption, which would take on a super-computer a few thousand years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: Basically, if you don't have the decryption code already, it isn't going to happen... Once you factory reset you deleted the key, so it is more likely that you will be struck by lightning while being bitten by a shark than you getting the data off this card in your lifetime without the encryption key.