# How to decrypt (FBE) file-based encryption Adoptable Storage Android 12

Tags: root-access, data-recovery, encryption, adoptable-storage

I backed up encrypted data of adopted internal storage on my PC & then Formatted the SD card as portable storage.

But I have not factory reset my android system so the key
for decryption must be inside the Android system internal storage.

Now I have the encrypted data stored on PC & key inside my Android system storage.
If I manage to extract the Key to decrypt the data stored on PC.
Then
How to use that key to decrypt the data?
And where to do the decryption?
On Android or on PC?? And how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: please give sample of *"encrypted data stored on PC"* so we can double check the linked answer applies or is maybe outdated for android 12

Comment: Almost all of the backed up data is .jpg files i.e. Images & some of it are Videos (30gb of media out of total 31Gb). Solution linked seems outdated atleast to me on reading it. I am currently on Android 12 with Root access to the device. Can someone help me out here on how to make the backed up data Readable again???

Comment: according to documentation *if the device is configured to use file-based encryption (FBE) on its internal storage, then adoptable storage uses both FBE and metadata encryption.* if you can see plain file names, this leads to conclusion files are not encrypted at all (metadata encryption does not show file names). more likely you faced MTP bug and files are corrupt

Comment: This went over the top of my head. Can u explain it in layman's terms? Can the decryption Key present inside the Android system internal storage be used to make the backed up data usable again? Can the Key make the data Readable again? If so, how to use that Key to Read the data or Decrypt the data and Make it usable again?

Comment: I said, your files are not encrypted but simply corrupted. yes it's possible to decrypt on PC. but I don't know how to do that for FBE. consult expert for android 12

Comment: Is it possible to plug your Android device into your PC and navigate to the files via your Android device and decrypt the files that way?

Comment: Try this to retrieve the files: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mate-9-how-to-retrieve-encrypted-files-from-a-broken-system-userdata-partition.3894561/

Comment: @Lavyansi do you know files are encrypted same way as file on data? guess the key is only for metadata decryption then https://github.com/LineageOS/android_system_vold/blob/lineage-20.0/FsCrypt.cpp#L276