# SD card Adopted as Internal storage

Tags: encryption, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, data-corruption

Using Pixel experience Rom based on Android 12 on Nokia 6.1+.

Mistakenly adopted SD card as internal storage
and while the files/data was being transferred from phone to Sd card/ shared internal storage,
it got interrupted by a notification and I clicked on it to see it thinking that the file must be transferring in the background window.
Then
on seeing the files(Images)
I was able to see just their thumbnails and on selecting individually the files just kept loading.
Then
I removed the sd card without 'EJECT'
which made the matters worse.
So
I then, copied this corrupted data to my PC.
I don't know if while adopting the sd card as internal storage,the files got encrypted or not, as I was able to see the image names as they were stored before in the phone.

Then I formatted the sd card as Portable storage.
Then tried to copy and paste the data stored on my PC to SD card hoping it would be readable but it wasn't.
Then
using this sd card and another Sd card experimented by copying and pasting the PC data to then both as Portable and internal storage multiple times just to make the data readable but couldn't.

Can this data stored on my PC become readable again?
Can it be repaired somehow ?
Almost all of the 30gb data is images and few videos.

Can somebody help me to Get my data repaired and become readable.
How to do so ?

Plz help!

Comment: Based on [your comment about 30 GB data on the previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247642/how-to-decrypt-fbe-file-based-encryption-adoptable-storage-android-12#comment332527_247642), is it the same issue as your previous questions?

Comment: It's related to that. Are there any chances to make the corrupted & encrypted data readable again?

Comment: Realistically since the data is encrypted AND corrupt, and you have reformatted the SD card (meaning the encryption key is gone now), the data is lost...

Comment: What if I didn't forget or format my 1st SD card as Portable storage & just adopted another Sd card as internal storage. Would the Device be containing 2 separate decryption keys for each card in that case?