# Finding Decryption Key and how to use it to decrypt

Tags: root-access, encryption, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, data-corruption

Nokia 6.1+ device using pixel experience ROM based on Android 12.

- Adopted SD card as internal storage and removed it without '**Eject**'.
- Afterwards couldn't read the data even on the device itself.
- Copied the encrypted data ( mainly images and videos) to my PC.
- Tried to make the data readable again, copied and pasted the data to another 2nd SD card by adopting it as internal storage, didn't work.
- Adopted it as Portable storage as well. Could not read the data any way.
- I Adopted 2nd sd card as Portable and internal storage multiple times but neither formatted nor "Forget" the 1st SD card

1 - Does the device store separate Keys for different sd cards when they're adopted as internal storage?

2. Can the **Original 1st key** still be inside the device system files as I didn't format or changed any system files?
3. If just one latest key is present inside the device, could this key decrypt my data which was 1st encrypted??
4. Could this last key be used to deduce the 1st key ?

I have Root access on my device and Encrypted data on my PC.
Using CX file manager can access data/misc/vold folder which contains the decryption key
But those KEYS inside are not being read by my android device.

5. How to access and Read the decryption Key(s)?
6. Then Can I copy and paste the Vold folder and save the keys on PC?
7. How to read and then use the decryption key to decrypt the encrypted data stored on my PC?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers). Sorry, I'm going to close all your previous questions as a dupe to this question because asking the same question multiple times is discouraged. Please continue the progress on this question so that the info is centralized to help potential answerers. The fact that no one has answered probably means that they don't know the solution, or it's otherwise a really difficult/impossible task, so *please be patient*. Thanks for your understanding, I really hope for the best outcome.

Comment: This seems like a bug in your custom ROM. File based encryption is static whose keys are within the device at secure place so removing the adoptable storage and putting back in is like powering off your phone and turning it on once again. FBE keys for adoptable storage are tied to its GUID which doesn't change. Can you read data which is on your phone?

Comment: No the data (mainly images & videos) is not readable in the device. As I said, I removed the adopted SD card without 'EJECT' and Data/Misc/Vold can be accessed as I hv root access. There are multiple .key folders inside it but they are not being read on Android.

Comment: The ROM has corrupted your filesystem. Removing the adopted storage without ejection does not corrupt the data. It works once again after reinserting the storage. Your filesystem cannot be repaired because what data block is causing the ROM to not recognize your filesystem is not known. Once you know the error with experiments, you will be able to fix it. Try analyzing the raw filesystem metadata with some tools.

Answer (score 0):

According to your other questions, what you want is decrypting adoptable storage on **FBE** file encryption.

Nobody knows and nobody will answer. All the information is outdated, it's all about FDE block device encryption.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142384/discussion-between-abhishek-rawat-and-alecxs).